# RichTextBox does not support "\r" or CR and replaces "\r" with "\n"

Tags: c#, string, winforms, newline, richtextbox

I am trying to set a string of data to RichTextBox control in windows form but RichTextBox Text property replaces all occurrence of "\r" with "\n".

I also tried re-replacing the "\n":
RichTextBox.Text.Replace("\n", "\r") and RichTextBox.Text.Replace("\n", "\r\n") but unfortunately no luck.

```
RichTextBox1.Text = "Abhi\rRa\r123"; //Textbox stores as Abhi\nRa\n123 
RichTextBox1.Text = this.RichTextBox1.Text.Replace("\n", "\r"); //Silly as .Text will eventually replace \r to \n.
```

How can be allow the string to be stored in a textbox with "\r" and not letting "\r" be replaced by "\n"????

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why bother? You can always replace the char back, when needed. - Note the RTB is about formatted text; it wants to wrap text where needed and uses paragraphs instead of newlines. And. Changing the Text directly  will mess up previous formatting..

Answer (score 2):

`RichTextBox` **seems** to have a property `Text`, but the `Rtf` property is the real one and the only place where the text is stored.

When you add a text that contains `\r` (or `\r\n`) it will be **converted** to `\par` in the `Rtf` property. And when you copy the `Text` back somewhere it will be **reconstructed** from the `Rtf` substituting the `\par` by the **regular RTB line break character**, which is `\n`.

So: It understands `\r` but **it doesn't store** it.

(Btw: If you add text that contains the reversed sequence: `\n\r` it will be converted to two `\par`s. )

So, if you want to keep the `\r` either switch back with a `Replace("\r","\n")` after copying from the `Text` or store it elsewhere.

Comment: I need to show this string with '\r' in front end textbox. Even if i store it else somewhere still at last i need to populate it in textbox before displaying it to user.

Comment: Well, you can never 'see' the formatting characters anyway. So what do you mean by _I need to show this string with '\r' in front end textbox_ ??

Comment: "show this string with '\r' in front end textbox" means that i need to retain \r in the string while the string is shown in the textbox and \r makes the following string in next line. For Example: suppose string is: "Abhi\rRana" then in the textbox i need to display Abhi in 1 line and Rana on next down line, here \r acts like \n is what i am thinking about.

Comment: Well both actual TextBoxes and RichTextboxes do that, no? Both characters are equivalent here. Of course, when using a TextBox you must turn on `MuliLine`..

Comment: No, that's the whole point here, As of now rich textbox converts "Abhi\rRana" to "Abhi\nRana" and then displays Abhi on 1st line and Rana on next following line. But there is a functionality in my project to track if segment end delimiters is line feed carriage return. Ex:  010 i.e., "\n" or 013 i.e., "\r". As of now i want segment delimiter to be 013 i.e., "\r" but rich textbox automatically converts it to 010 i.e., "\n".

Comment: If you want to track them you need to analyze them before feeding the text into the RTB.